# Docker auto update host file for nginx webserver container

Tags: nginx, docker, ember.js, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to access my Docker container with an other url than `localhost`.
The container is a `nginx` webserver serving static files of an `Ember` application.
My `nginx`configuration looks like this :

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  my-app.dev;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/log/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    root           html;
    #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
    #    include        fastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}
```

And I would like to access my application through `my-app.dev:8080`. So my `Dockerfile` looks like this :

```
FROM nginx:alpine

COPY ./my-app-nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

COPY ./dist /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 80
```

And my `docker-compose.yml` file like this :

```
version: "2"

services:
  web:
    restart: always
    image: me/my-app:latest
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile

    container_name: my-app

    # Keep the stdin open, so we can attach to our app container's process
    # and do things such as debugging, etc:
    stdin_open: true

    # Enable sending signals (CTRL+C, CTRL+P + CTRL+Q) into the container:
    tty: true

    ports:
      - "8080:80"
```

Everything almost work excpet that I have to modify my `host`file on my host machine to map `127.0.0.1 my-app.dev` otherwise it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that what you want is gonna break the encapsulation principle which is one of the advantages of using docker.

Once you have to modify the host machine to make it work in some way, you're going out of docker rules.

I'm not saying that it isn't possible, but you should think it better before break up the isolation.

Imagine if I can remap `google.com` only running a set of docker containers, it's actually a security concern.

If you want to identify your apps in your host, modifying manually the `/etc/hosts` file is the safest way to keep the control over your host system.

Comment: Ok but how you solve the problem when you want to run multiple containers on the same port ? If I'm only able to access it at localhost and without different url ?

Comment: You can run all your containers in the same port e.g. 80, they aren't gonna be published to your host as long as you don't say: `- 80:80`, which means you want the container's port to be published to your host.

You should have only one container with the 80 port published, `nginx` would be your case, and the rest of the containers can run in 80 port without publishing it, those containers can actually reach each other by using the hostname which is the container's name if you're using `docker-compose`.

Look at this: https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Comment: I look at the link but it doesn't seem to solve my "problem". But if you say that I just can't have multiple containers publishing on port 80 that's it.

Comment: You CAN have multiple containers running in 80 port as long as you don't publish those ports to the host.

Remember, they are isolated, no matter what port you use inside the container.